# Not able to pass strings through named pipes (FIFOs) in multithreaded processes

Tags: c, pthreads, popen, file-descriptor, mkfifo

I am trying to use **'FIFOs'** and **'popen()'** function for communication between multiple processes. Also, the first process is **multithreaded** for reading and writing operations.

Following is the C code for the processes:

**P1 process (Q1.c)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

void* reader()
{   
    char string[64];
    int rfd = open("FIFO",O_RDONLY);
    while(1)
    {
        read(rfd,string,sizeof(string));
        sleep(10);
        printf("%s\n",string);
    }   
}
void* writer()
{
    char string[64];
    FILE *wfd = popen("./Q1_1","w");
    int fd = fileno(wfd);
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%s",string);
        write(fd,string,sizeof(string));
    }
    pclose(wfd);
}
int main()
{
    if(mkfifo("FIFO",0666)==-1)
    {
        if(errno!=EEXIST)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    pthread_t r_thread,s_thread;
    pthread_create(&r_thread,NULL,reader,NULL);
    pthread_create(&s_thread,NULL,writer,NULL);
    pthread_join(r_thread,NULL);
    pthread_join(s_thread,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

**P2 Process (Q1_1.c)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fd = popen("./Q1_2","w");
    char string[64];
    int ffd = fileno(fd);
    printf("P2Check");
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%s",string);
        write(ffd,string,sizeof(string));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**P3 Process (Q1_2.c)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    char string[64];
    if(mkfifo("FIFO",0666)==-1)
    {
        if(errno!=EEXIST)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    int wfd = open("FIFO",O_WRONLY);
    printf("P3Check");
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%s",string);
        write(wfd,string,sizeof(string));
    }
}
```

However, after executing process P1 and providing input, there is no output as if the process is stuck. I suspect there is some issue with the multithreading but not sure.

Comment: Start by adding some more debug output for all your programs and threads. And check what all system calls (especially `read` and `write`) returns.

Comment: Hmm, I did debug outputs and it seems that P2 is not able to get the string that is given by P1... not sure if scanf() is unable to read that or I have implemented it incorrectly.

Comment: Perhaps a buffering issue? Try to use `fgets` instead of `scanf` *everywhere* and make sure that the newline is included when you write the data.

Comment: @IshanJoshi: When replying to other people's comments, if you want the other person to be notified of your reply, you must use the `@` syntax with the other person's name. Otherwise, the person you are replying to may not notice your reply. You will automatically be notified of any comments to your question, but other people will not automatically be notified, so you must use the `@` syntax. Press the "Help" button when writing a comment for further information.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Oh thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Okay by doing that change, it perfectly prints the string for 1 iteration. However, for subsequent iterations, it just prints a newline regardless of the input.

Comment: After some experimenting I managed to get it to work. I replaced the writing to the sub-processes (the ones where you use `popen`) to use plain C stdio calls instead of using the file descriptor and `write`. For example in the Q1 program I replaced `write(fd,string,sizeof(string));` with `fprintf(wfd, "%s\n", string); fflush(wfd)`. I updated the `Q1_1` program similarly. My ***guess*** is that there was a problem with buffers when you bypassed the C stdio file stream by writing directly to the descriptor.

Comment: See [here](https://gist.github.com/pileon/5c38a6038bf5f695016d41d90bcda091) for the code I managed to get to work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yep that worked... it seems like the buffer wasn't cleared properly in my example and the char[] contained the '\n' character somehow. Anyway thanks for your time and help ^-^